# MS Access SQL Switch Function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have several tables with the same data structure (they're filled with a bunch of stuff, in separate .accdb files to account for the 2GB limit) and need to retrieve info from one of them based on a field in a form.

Upon researching I came up with the following, but it won't seem to work.

```
SELECT MyNumber, MyName, MyPage, MyDrawing
FROM Switch([Forms]![View_Info]![Contract] = "Contract1", "tblContract1", [Forms]![View_Info]![Contract] = "Contract2", "tblContract2")
WHERE (MyNumber = [Forms]![View_Info]![MyNumber])
```

Syntax error in FROM clause.
In this example I only used 4 fields and 2 tables but in fact there are around 9 tables and 20 fields in each that I wish to retrieve.

Can someone shed some light on this? I have a really hard time with SQL, so I apologize if this is quite basic.

Thanks in advance, Rafael.

Comment: `SWITCH()` is a function that returns a scalar value, typically used in a `SELECT` clause.

Comment: I searched for a _Select Case_ or _Switch Case_ alternative and found `SWITCH()`. Didn't notice it wouldn't take string inputs...

Comment: That's not exactly the real issue. In MS Access, functions are not allowed in `FROM` and `JOIN` that refer to tables.

Comment: By the way, consider a database redesign. Even with MS Access' individual file limit, normalization should be exercised. Having numbered tables like *tblContract1*, *tblContract2*, ... is not optimal setup. Keep ALL contracts in one database, other items in other databases and link as needed.

Comment: It's just an example, Contracts have different names because although they have some equivalent fields, there's things specific to each that I would like to leave out... But maybe I'll redesign it in the future. Probably not anytime soon though :D

Comment: Understood. Different named tables is a challenge. You can have an indicator field in the single *contracts* table for the different names and as many fields as relevant (missing for non-applicable rows) but maybe even those can be single columns of different values. In fact, your attempted `SWITCH` logic call will then work in a `WHERE` clause!

Comment: You'd be surprised how few business logic cannot be resolved with [normalization](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics). If you find an example, please share! Plus, storage is more efficient, redundancy and complex queries are avoided, and you can exercise referential integrity (one-to-one, one-to-many relationships) better! Start today with a redesign. Good luck!

Comment: @Parfait Ended up doing a redesign, took me a while but things are smoother. Thanks for the tip, would've been up to my knees in s**t real soon :p

Comment: Great to hear and thanks for reporting back! Yes, good design (painful from existing setup) helps in long run.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return the table name from a function in the SQL FROM clause. If your table is determined dynamically, then you must build the SQL command string dynamically.

```
Dim tableName As String, sql As String

tableName = Switch(...)
sql = "SELECT ... FROM [" & tableName & "] WHERE ..."
```

---

As @forpas explains in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56777487/880990), you can use a UNION query, but this will always query all the tables. Since the filter is not based on a table column, the filtering will occur on the client side, i.e. in your application.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't refresh the page for a while. Removed this part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this UNION:

```
SELECT MyNumber, MyName, MyPage, MyDrawing
FROM tblContract1
WHERE (MyNumber = [Forms]![View_Info]![MyNumber]) AND [Forms]![View_Info]![Contract] = "Contract1"
UNION
SELECT MyNumber, MyName, MyPage, MyDrawing
FROM tblContract2
WHERE (MyNumber = [Forms]![View_Info]![MyNumber]) AND [Forms]![View_Info]![Contract] = "Contract2"
```

Each query of the UNION contains in the WHERE clause the condition:

```
[Forms]![View_Info]![Contract] = "Contract?"
```

Comment: Now complete this for 9 contract tables which reside across multiple databases! Ouch... OP would do better with redesign. But this answer shows the complex queries required of separate named tables.

Comment: Really, 9? I should have read better the question. Well I'm not the one to write the full code. I hope the OP knows how to write the rest.